# Convolutional neural networks and 3D images

Tags: tensorflow

I am interested in applying CNNs to 3D images (i.e. medical data). 
Does TensorFlow already incorporate this functionality?

Answer (score 13):

TensorFlow now supports [3D convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv3d) and [3D pooling](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/max_pooling3d) in the master branch.

You can use them with 5D tensors as input with shape: `[batch_size, depth, height, width, channels]`.

Comment: what about 3D transpose (deconvolution)?

Comment: Lucky you, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/3049) under way which would add support for that. See also [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2467)

Comment: How'd you get so good at tensorflow? Lol, you are always spot on with your answers! Thanks!

Comment: Haha I work using TensorFlow so with time comes wisdom ;)

Comment: These links are now giving 404s, but I'm not sure how to best update them. I did find this example:https://gist.github.com/dansileshi/21b52113ce0ecb6c0f56d6f7534bbaca

Answer (score 3):

No, the current implementations are made for 2D images (functions like nn.conv2d). They support multiple channels (eg RGB) and it is possible to express 3D images as a multichannel 2D image (each z-slice is a channel), but this isn't always ideal. Additionally for using these sort of approaches you need substantial amounts of image data which is typically difficult to come by in the medical area.

Update: both TensorFlow and Theano (subsequently Keras, Lasagne, etc) now all support 3D operations as stated above. It is important to note that 3D operations are much more computationally and memory intensive than a similar 2D operation.

Comment: How is it any different from the conv2D? It seems to me as if Conv3D is batch+image which creates batch+featuremaps. 
in conv2d, we have image with channels, which creates kxWxH feature maps. 
you have x number of images? then x number of featuremaps will be crated . 
AM I wrong ?

Comment: Well a conv2d is a 4 dimensional matrix ( image count, channel count, x width, y width) a conv3d operation is a 5 dimensional matrix.

Comment: Yeah, Thats right, I just want to if the operation is the same, to be honest I'm lost how the operation is carried out. when we talk about temporal stride, what does that mean? how do we do strides for temporal dimension? I know 5 frames, in a row is called the temporal dimension. (image count, depth, channel count, x width, y width ), which depth here would be 5. denoting there are 5 frames of let say e.g 200x200x3 . 
so how does stride makes sense in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow implementation for 3D Convolutional Neural Networks has been provided with the following open source projects:

[Lip Reading - Cross Audio-Visual Recognition using 3D Convolutional Neural Networks](https://github.com/astorfi/3D-convolutional-Audio-Visual)

[Using 3D Convolutional Neural Networks for Speaker Verification](https://github.com/astorfi/3D-convolutional-speaker-recognition)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CNN with 3D images, a possible alternative is to use this [Caffe PR](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2049).
You will need to convert your data to HDF5 format.